# Which library is the best to obfuscate code in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, obfuscation, cordova-plugin-proguard

How can we obfuscate the code in ionic?

The best known approach that most people use is

1. Jasob (I haven’t used it, but many recommend this tool.)
2. JScrambler (Their official article to work with Ionic is attached with this email, which I have used and recommend.).

are there any other ways to obfuscate it?

Can we use proguard from the Android build? Not sure how will it effect it. But remaining javascript files would be still not obfuscated I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using JSDefender for almost a year now. It has helped me obfuscating Ionic projects. You can try the trial period to see if it is adapted for your project as well.

Comment: what is the price you paid?